# Как отправлять команды 3D-принтеру (Ардуино) с помощью Raspberry Pi?

Tags: arduino

Некоторые 3d-принтеры не имеют функцию автономной печати, т.е. для печати их обязательно нужно по USB подключать к ПК. Есть принтер, построенный на основе Arduino, общающийся с компом через Repiteir-host. В самом принтере есть слот для SD-карты, но чтобы с неё выбрать модель для печати и начать печатать все равно нужен ПК.
 Хочу к принтеру подключить текстовый экранчик для отображения файлов на SD-карточке и блок с тремя кнопками (вверх, вниз, печать). Всем этим хозяйством будет управлять Raspberry Pi. Он будет и отдавать команды принтеру вместо ПК. Команды с Repetier-host уже перехватил. Нужно как-то зашить их в Raspberry. 
 С этим девайсом раньше не работал. Каким образом это можно сделать? Я знаю, что Raspberry это одноплатный комп, но как на нем можно это реализовать?
Есть идеи? Особенно меня интересует способ подачи команд 3d-принтеру.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку протокол общения между хостом (ПК) и Raspberry Pi вам уже известен, то всё, что требуется - это написать приложение, которое будет запускаться на Raspberry при загрузке системы. Самое сложное будет написать программу для дисплея и кнопок. Почитать про разработку приложений для Raspberry Pi можно [здесь](http://raspberrypi.ru/blog/readblog/149.html)